# Dropdownlist with check boxes (mvc3/jquery)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

QQ: Hi I need (intuitive) functionality that allows a user to select multiple items in a drop down list.  Are there any dropdownlists jquery/mvc3/razor that allows for a check box to appear to the left within the list item to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Google search keyword 'multiselect'

Comment: Neverever is correct, the UX you would be essentially creating is a multiselect. If you must have a checkbox for what ever reason, a few have been provided below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking for this jQuery plugin(s):

- http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/
- http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/04/jquery-multiselect/